# Can't access Firestore after etting "allow all authenticated"

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm initializing FireStore in my Chrome extension like they explain in the docs:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
initializeApp({apiKey:'...', ...});
```

Then I call `setDoc` to store a document. Everything is fine when I set `allow read, write: true` in the access rules. But when I change it to `allow read, write: if request.auth != null`, all my Firestore requests start failing with `Error adding document: FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

I assumed that providing my Firestore API key and other data in the initialization code would automatically make it authenticated. However, Firestore thinks that my requests are anonymous for some reason. How do I fix this?

Here's my config:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The Firebase API key isn't for authentication with security rules. You must be logged in using Firebase authentication. The rules check user's ID Token from Firebase auth. Are you using FIrebase auth?

Comment: No, I'm not using Firebase auth. I'm developing a Chrome extension and using the native API for authenticating users.

Comment: Hi, may I know which Firebase SDK version are you using?

Comment: I'm using `9.0.0-beta.7`

Comment: Can you perhaps change the version to 8.7.0-2021528231051, using npm install firebase@8.7.0-2021528231051 and let us know if it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `request.auth` check if the request is coming from authenticated user in firebase authentication.

The Firestore API key is only to send the request to the correct firebase project, but it doesn't make the `request.auth != null`.

You need to authenticate against firebase authentication in order to get `request.auth != null`. But in your case I beleive you don't want the users to authenticate, so you need some other security rule to get what you really want to check.